# Completely remove unnamed instance from stage and group

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, destroy, removechild

So I have a bunch of instances of a movie clip "fruit". They are all unnamed.

I added them in a mother movie clip named "fruitGroup".

What the code is supposed to do is when any fruit instance is clicked, play its animation, and destroy it *forever*.

It works well, until your mouse is over the coords of the previously destroyed fruit. The fruit pops back into existence!

```
fruitGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,fruitOver);
fruitGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fruitclick);
fruitGroup.mouseEnabled = false;

function fruitOver(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.play();

}
function fruitclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
    e.target.gotoAndPlay(82);
    if (e.target._currentframe==100)
    {
        e.target.removeChild(e.target);
    }

}
```

EDIT: I didn't really clarify my setup. Apart from the fruitGroup and my CLICK listener, there are 2 more things to my setup. The base symbol has 100 frames. 1-81 are a wiggle animation played on mouseover, 82-100 are a fade-out animation played on click. Maybe the destruction should happen INSIDE of the base symbol at frame 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do two things. First, you have to add an Event.ENTER_FRAME listener to the one of your fruits that was clicked, in order to make it handle the event when its currentFrame will become 100, and second, to remove your fruit that's playing you have to do this:

```
e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,yourFunction);
```

Note the `parent` in reference, you have to check if there is a parent, or you'll run into issues.

Edit: Okay, let me clarify the answer. You retain your MouseEvent.CLICK listener, but make it like this:

```
fruitGroup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,fruitclick);
function fruitclick(e:MouseEvent)
{
    if (e.target is Fruit) {
        e.target.gotoAndPlay(82);
        if (!e.target.hasEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME)) 
            e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,endPlay);
    }
}
```

Then you add an ENTER_FRAME listener like this:

```
function endPlay(e:Event):void 
{
    if (e.target._currentframe==100)
    {
        e.target.parent.removeChild(e.target);
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,endPlay);
    }
}
```

This code can still reside on the main timeline, or it can be in any class that has access to `fruitGroup` to initiate listening for clicks.

How does this work: When you click on a fruit, the function `fruitClick` is called, with the event's target set to the clicked fruit. We now have the reference there - good, now we assign it a listener and make it play the animation you want. The listener activates each frame with event's target being the very same fruit, and once its `currentFrame` reaches 100, we call its parent to release the fruit off itself (it'll most likely be `fruitGroup`, but if not, this won't give an error), and remove the now-obsolete listener.

Comment: So I should go *inside* the movieclip of the fruit, and add an EnterFrame, which does what? Didn't really understand, sorry!

Comment: I tried the code, but now the CLICK does not do anything. I think the problem is the first if (e.target is Fruit). Is it supposed to check for the name of the base symbol? I tried changing Fruit to fruit, but still no luck!

Comment: Tried every freaking solution on the net, even went as far as to try and make my own class...it all works well, but then again, the fruits aren't supposed to reappear.

It's driving me mad!

Comment: Umm. I didn't tell you to drop your `MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER` listener. My bad. Or, if you badly need that listener, you should rework it to better suit your needs.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that I want to have an animation play on Mouseover. The fruits are supposed to wiggle when over'd, and disappear when clicked. How would I implement this if I drop the mouseover/how would I rework it?

Comment: You need to check if your e.target is already playing the "disappear" animation, if so, ignore the event. Also you should not use `play()` for your wiggle animation, but use `gotoAndPlay("startWiggle")` instead, change the parameter to the correct frame of your wiggle sequence.

Comment: Well it does have a `gotoAndStop(1)` at 81 (please check newly edited question).

Comment: Well, yes, if you want, you can add a script to the `fruit` MC on frame 100 that will spell `stop(); parent.removeChild(this);`, and don't use enter frame listener. Be careful though, you will need to stop your wiggle animation somewhere at frame 81, otherwise you could accidentally have your wiggling turn into fade and boom, you've lost an apple.

Comment: OH EM GEE, finally! Mi hiro :)